# Can we use longest common subsequene algorithm(LCS) for searches?

Tags: algorithm, web, data-structures

LCS(algorithm to find longest subsequence between two strings)  in searches?
Websites like olx(online exchange website) which has search bar to search item for buyer.So,like that if i want build some application which is similar to olx.Can i use LCS for searching any item?if no,what else can you all suggest?

Comment: What is LCS what is olx? Please put more information in your question. what have you tried so far? If you are looking for an autocomplete searchbar with advanced filtering check out elasicsearch or Milisearch.

Comment: i have edited it again!

Comment: If you build an application you usually don't use search algorithm yourself. You use Database with builtin search feature or use dedicated software for searches like ElasticSearch. Unless you want to write your own database, but if you don't know what algorithm to use than this is probably not for you.